# Subtracting time from two different file and write it into new file in python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I am having a bit of difficulty, i have two type of time data and  I want to substract it. the first data looks a bit like this, the # is an identifier for one event :

```
# 04:13:53.7
# 06:04:37.0
# 07:36:30.7
```

The second data is like the this, inside the 'sta phase time wt' is an identifier for one event:

```
sta phase time wt
GENI P 04:14:14.4 1.0
GENI S 04:14:29.9 1.0
SMPI P 04:14:22.6 1.0
SMPI S 04:14:44.7 1.0
ATNI P 04:17:30.1 1.0
SOEI P 04:17:39.4 1.0
sta phase time wt
GENI P 06:04:45.7 1.0
GENI S 06:04:49.5 1.0
JAY P 06:04:51.9 1.0
JAY S 06:05:01.6 1.0
ERPI P 06:05:33.4 1.0
FAKI P 06:06:26.9 0.0
SWI P 06:06:42.0 0.0
BSMI P 06:06:50.4 0.0
SAUI P 06:06:58.4 0.0
KRAI P 06:07:19.9 0.0
sta phase time wt
GENI P 07:36:52.4 1.0
GENI S 07:37:10.7 1.0
JAY P 07:36:58.3 1.0
JAY S 07:37:16.9 1.0
sta phase time wt
```

I wanted to substract the time from the second data under the 'time' column to the first data. I am expecting something like this for the output if possible:

```
sta phase time wt
GENI P 20.0 1.0
GENI S 36.0 1.0
SMPI P 29.0 1.0
SMPI S 51.0 1.0
ATNI P 216 1.0
SOEI P 225.0 1.0
sta phase time wt
.....
..... and so on
```

I probably need to round up the time first but, any help would be a big help

Comment: First you need to have those data in a `list`. and then in a for loop, you need to convert them to strptime - `datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M:%S.f")`.

Then you have to get the difference, By looping through the 2nd dataset and also getting the minimum of the subtract result for each time on the 1st dataset - `min([abs(2nd_dataset - time) for time in 1st dataset])`

Answer (score 0):

We can do that by first parsing the time data in both files, calculating the time difference, and then writing the output to a new file.

Here is an example, replace the corresponding variable corresponding to the files name you want, `first_data.txt`, `second_data.txt`, and `output.txt`.

```
from datetime import datetime

def parse_first_data(data):
    events = []
    for line in data:
        if line.startswith("#"):
            time_str = line.strip("#").strip()
            events.append(datetime.strptime(time_str, "%H:%M:%S.%f"))
    return events

def parse_second_data(data):
    events = []
    for line in data:
        if line.startswith("sta"):
            continue
        elif line.startswith("GENI") or line.startswith("JAY") or line.startswith("SMPI") or line.startswith("ATNI") or line.startswith("SOEI"):
            parts = line.strip().split()
            time_str = parts[2]
            events.append((parts[0], parts[1], datetime.strptime(time_str, "%H:%M:%S.%f"), float(parts[3])))
    return events

with open("first_data.txt", "r") as f:
    first_data = f.readlines()

first_events = parse_first_data(first_data)

with open("second_data.txt", "r") as f:
    second_data = f.readlines()

second_events = parse_second_data(second_data)

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    i = 0
    for first_time, second_event in zip(first_events, second_events):
        sta, phase, time, wt = second_event
        time_diff = (time - first_time).total_seconds()
        f.write(f"{sta} {phase} {time_diff:.1f} {wt}\n")
        i += 1
        if i == len(second_events) or (i < len(second_events) and second_events[i][0] == "GENI"):
            f.write("sta phase time wt\n")
            i = 0
```

Comment: I do not really understand what is happening but this is the output:
GENI P 20.7 1.0
sta phase time wt
GENI S -6607.1 1.0
sta phase time wt
SMPI P -12128.1 1.0
sta phase time wt
SMPI S -34813.4 1.0
sta phase time wt
ATNI P -52786.5 1.0
sta phase time wt
SOEI P 3023.5 1.0
sta phase time wt
GENI P 9328.1 1.0
sta phase time wt
GENI S -19109.6 1.0
sta phase time wt
JAY P -19286.8 1.0

Comment: For additional information, the 'sta' does not always start with the mentioned above